# Manually invoking PropertyChanged on a list of models

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

In my ViewModel I have a property, which is a list of models:

```cs
private List<LocationModel> _locations = null;
public List<LocationModel> Locations
{
    get
    {
        return this._locations;
    }
    set
    {
        this._locations = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Locations");
    }
}
```

But the `LocationModel` class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so when I update a property of an item in the list, the UI doesn't get updated. I tried to achieve this by raising the event manually after altering the list item, but this didn't work. Can someone explain why doesn't this approach work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` only works with instance properties of an object implementing that interface. Not of *properties of a property* implementing the interface. `LocationModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want this to work. If you don't have the source code to LocationModel or you can't change it for whatever reason, you will need to wrap all properties that you want to react on in a wrapper class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You can wrap dynamically using <s>[DynamicProxy](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2009/12/23/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-using-dynamic-proxy/) (dead link)</s> [DynamicProxy (cached)](http://www.gigablast.com/get?q=Dynamic+proxy&c=main&d=160428780196&cnsp=0).

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned something about "pure model" in a comment to another response. I totally agree. But I never expose a model to the interface, I only expose ViewModels. Where is your LocationViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it with RaisePropertyChanged(null) , it'll tell the view to update everything, it's not recommended, the best solution is to implement INPC, or create a LocationWrapper that will implement it for you. If you want to go extreme you can use a dynamic object to proxy the model, or to use dynamic proxy to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried calling RaisePropertyChanged(null), but this also didn't work. And its not desirable to create some wrappers as I want to maintain some kind of "pure model".

Comment: You will have to raise the property changed from the object that bound to ui, and this is your pure model, so either give up the pure model or create a view model for the model.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ObservableCollection instead of List. Changes to items inside an ObservableCollection will trigger a notification to the View.

```
private ObservableCollection<LocationModel> _locations = null;
public ObservableCollection<LocationModel> Locations
    {
    get
    {
        return this._locations;
    }
    set
    {
        this._locations = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Locations");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but ObservableCollection tracks only collection changes such as insertion or removal of items.